# Automated fake mailbox

Tags: .net, email, automation, pop3

i'm about to start the development of a new automated-email application. The idea is that customers (or other external users) send emails to a mailbox and then an automated process will read them, extract their information and insert it into some database. It's a requirement that the emails have an standard format in order to be parsed (standard subject, etc.). 
The obvious thing to do would be to set up a process that periodically polls an ordinary mailbox, through pop-3 for example, processing the messages it finds. However, it would be for me much nicer to be able to process the emails as they arrive.  I was wondering then, is there any way to set up a process that acts as a fake email-box? do you know about any open-source implementation of something like that I can extend? I would prefer something already written in c#.

Thanks in advance for your help,
bernabé

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3042260/edit) your question to fix things like that

Comment: What type of mail server are you running?

Comment: I'm running no server yet. I could ask my customer to set up an standard pop-3 mailbox on one of their servers (that would be the polling choice). The other choice would be to become a mailbox (but i'm not sure about what protocol should I implement in that case)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to set up a local mail system with a mail retrieval agent (MRA) and mail delivery agent (MDA). A common combination is [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) for an MRA and either [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) or [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) for an MDA. The MRA downloads mail from your account (POP3, IMAP, etc.), and the MDA processes it to figure out what mailbox it belongs in. I know at least maildrop, but probably procmail as well, supports running arbitrary scripts on the messages, so you could use that to process each e-mail